# matching array content in azure documentdb

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, nosql

is there a way of producing following query?

```
{ 
  "user": { 
    "name": "john", 
    "tags": ["one", "two", "three"] 
  } 
}
```

now given an array of tags

```
["one","two","five"]
```

I want to select all users (distinct if possible) who have at least one tag in common with incoming tag array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write a user defined function to do this. For example, I searched for JavaScript array intersection in StackOverflow and found this: [Simplest code for array intersection in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript)

You can register this as a UDF in your collection, and then query like:

```
SELECT * FROM docs WHERE udf.ARRAY_INTERSECTS(docs.tags, ["a", "b", "c"]) != []
```

Note however that this requires a scan..

Comment: If you used a three-tag OR clause, would it use an index on the array?

Comment: Yes, if you used a three-tag OR, it would use the index.

Comment: could you give an example on how to write that query so it would use an index?

Comment: This will use the index: SELECT * FROM docs JOIN tag in docs.tags WHERE tag = "a" OR tag = "b" OR tag = "c"

Comment: And what about something like SELECT * FROM docs WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(docs.tags, "a") OR ARRAY_CONTAINS(docs.tags, "b") OR ARRAY_CONTAINS(docs.tags, "c")